# Getting error while making variables static in the scanner function in eclipse java

Tags: java, exception, static, filenotfoundexception

So basically I need the code to have access to the `pin` variable. But when I make `pin` static, Eclipse tells me to make all the variables before it static too. So I did that. But as soon as I make `file` static, the `Scanner(textFile)` gives the error:

> Unhandled exception type FileNotFoundException

What causes this issue? I need the variables to be static. Maybe if there was a way to make a non-static variable equal a static one.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class atmtester {
    atmtester() throws FileNotFoundException{}
    static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    private static float balance = 500;

    static String pinfile = "/Users/Pallav/Documents/Work/Computer Science/pin.txt";
    static File textFile = new File(pinfile);
    static Scanner fromfile = new Scanner(textFile); 
    static String pin = fromfile.nextLine();
```

I only need help for the stuff above. Below code is just for context as to why I need the static to be there.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {        
    System.out.print("Please enter your PIN: ");
    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        String theirpin = keyboard.next();
        if (theirpin.equals(pin)) {
            System.out.println("Correct PIN entered. Now taking you to menu...");
            break;
        } else if (!theirpin.equals(pin)) {
            int triesremaining = 0;
            triesremaining = 3 - i;
            System.out.println("*Incorrect PIN. You have " + triesremaining + " tries remaining*");
            if (triesremaining != 0)
                System.out.print("Enter the correct PIN: ");
            else if (i == 3) {
                System.err.println("\n*Card Blocked!*");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }

static void checkPin(String tocheckpin) {
    if (!tocheckpin.equals(pin)) {
        System.out.print("Incorrect Pin. You have 1 more try. Try again: ");
        tocheckpin = keyboard.next();
        if (!tocheckpin.equals(pin)) {
            System.err.println("*Card Blocked!*");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    } else if (tocheckpin.equals(pin)) {
    }
}
```

Comment: does the file exists? have you checked... are you trying to create it?

Answer (score 0):

You should do this:`static Scanner fromfile = new Scanner(textFile);`  under a function, can be main method or any other method because it will have an

> unhandled exception: FileNotFoundException

When you enclose Scanner statement inside a method, you can either use it under a try catch block or throw exception in the method itself such as

`a() throws FileNotFoundException{}`

And to answer why it is asking you to convert pin to static is:

1. main method is static and you can access pin either by creating an object of a class or declaring pin as static. Hence it demanded you to change it to static
2. After declaring pin, it asks you to convert all other variable to static because you are using
   -->fromfile in pin, that is `pin = fromfile.nextLine();`so you have to assign only static content to another static variables
   -->now textFile is being used by formfile.. so textFile should be made static
   --> now pinfile is assinged to textfile.. so pinfile should be changed to static.

You should understand that, static variables belongs to class itself and not the class instances

Answer (score 0):

> And I don't know why.

The reason for the compilation error is that `new Scanner(String)` can throw a `FileNotFoundException`.  This is a *checked exception*, and that means that it *must be* either caught ... or propagated.

The problem is that exceptions thrown by the initializers for a classes fields CANNOT be caught.

There are two ways to solve this:

1. You could do the initializations in a *static initializer block*; e.g.

   ```
   static File textFile = new File(pinfile);
   static Scanner fromfile;
   static String pin;
   static {
       try {
           fromFile = new Scanner(textFile); 
           pin = fromfile.nextLine();
       } catch (Exception ex) {
           pin = 0;
       }
   }
   ```
2. A better approach would be to put the initialization (and exception handling) into a static method:

   ```
   static String pin = readPinFromFile(pinFile);

   public static String readPinFromFile(String fileName) {
       // ... open file, read and close, handling exceptions
   }
   ```